# DevExtreme Angular: Intl vs Globalize

Tags: localization, globalization, devextreme, devextreme-angular

In DevExtreme(Angular), there is two methods for localize strings,number date and currency:

> 1. Intl
> 2. Globalize

I have tried both the method, but not able to find which one is better and why?

What is the difference between this two?

Which one should i use?

Answer (score 0):

Globalize is powerful in terms of features but harder to configure. Intl is simple and straightforward. I would suggest that you start with Intl and only if it's not enough then switch to Globalize.

Comment: how it is powerful in terms of features? can you explain?